# how to find the size of your app while its in development

Tags: android, android-studio, size

I want to know whats the size of my application when I look at my android studio project under properties it is something like 100MB is that the size of my app? if it is how can I decrease it?

**NOTE: I use pro guard already, I got rid of any extra libraries and I merged my adapters and model classes to decrease the amount of JAVA code.**

Comment: Build it and look at the size of the apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project in Android Studio,

**Step 1:**

Go to **Build -> Build APK(s)**

[image]

**Step 2:**

Go to the folder --> **PROJECT FOLDER -> app -> build -> outputs -> apk -> debug**

Or,

Click on **Event Logs -> locate apk**

[image]

**Check the size of your debug-apk**

**If you are using proguard for release build, build your release apk which will be in the release directory and you can check the size of your apk.**

Answer (score 1):

Build -> Analyze APK -> app-debug.apk then click OK

[image]

You can see here the summary of the file size
If it is not working try to Build APK first

to reduce your APK size you can follow this link
https://medium.com/exploring-code/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in continuously keeping track of your APK size as you merge into your master branch, you can take a look at these two github actions. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/apk-metric-upload : This one maintains the latest master branch's size in your own repo artifact, while this action : https://github.com/marketplace/actions/apk-size-tracker compares your feature branch's size with master's size. It also provides the capability to set a threshold (per PR) on incoming PR's to not allow the apk size from increasing too much.